# How to interpolate a single column of data to match the shape of another column of data?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

Sorry if the title is confusing, I couldn't really think how to concisely phrase it.

I have two `xy` files,  both of which cover the same range in the x-axis (0 to 130), however one of them has 109 samples and the other has 81 - formatted as follows:

```
x1 data1
...
x109 data109
```

and

```
x1 data1
...
x81 data81
```

I would like to interpolate the second one so that it also has 109 samples which will allow me to directly compare the data at each given location along the x axis. Or maybe even interpolate both of them so that they each have a round 100 samples.

From a bit of research I *think* [Scipy spline](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html) will do what I am after, however I am a little confused how to make it work.

Any help would be appreciated. If you know another way to do it I am open to it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UnivariateSpline` code you link to is a lower-level routine — it's probably better to use [`scipy.interpolate.interp1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html) for your case.

As far as your data goes, you should be able to read the files using [`np.loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html), extract the columns into numpy arrays, and then use `interp1d` like this:

```
x1, y1 = np.loadtxt('file1.txt').transpose()
x2, y2 = np.loadtxt('file2.txt').transpose()

# interpolate (x2, y2) onto grid x1
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
func = interp1d(x2, y2, kind='cubic')
y2_interp = func(x1)
```